# decoding octal escape sequences with awk

Tags: awk

Let's suppose that you got octal escape sequences in a stream:

```
backslash \134 is escaped as \134134
single quote ' and double quote \042
linefeed `\012` and carriage return `\015`
%s &
etc...
```

<sup>**note:** In my input the escaped characters are limited to `0x01-0x1F 0x22 0x5C 0x7F`</sup>

How can you revert those escape sequences back to their corresponding character with `awk`?

While `awk` is able to understand them out-of-box when used in a literal string or as parameter argument, I can't find the way to leverage this capability when the escape sequence is part of the data. For now I'm using one `gsub` per escape sequence but it doesn't feel efficient.

Here's the expected output for the given sample:

```
backslash \ is escaped as \134
single quote ' and double quote "
linefeed `
` and carriage return `
%s &
etc...
```

Comment: Does it need to be `awk`? With perl it would be `perl -n -e 's/\\(\d{3})/chr(oct($1))/ge; print'` to process stdin.

Comment: Actually replace `\d` above with `[0-7]` to be more rigorous.

Comment: @Gene I would prefer to stick to standard tools but nice `perl` solution, I'll upvote it if you post it as an answer

Comment: @EdMorton Well, a backslash shall always be followed by 3 octal digits in the input

Comment: No worries. Fwiw, if performance is any issue the perl version will probably be considerably faster.   One more iteration using -p instead of -n `perl -p -e 's/\\([0-7]{3})/chr(oct($1))/ge'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk for `strtonum()` and lots of meaningfully-named variables to show what each step does:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function octs2chars(str,        head,tail,oct,dec,char) {
    head = ""
    tail = str
    while ( match(tail,/\\[0-7]{3}/) ) {
        oct  = substr(tail,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
        dec  = strtonum(0 oct)
        char = sprintf("%c", dec)
        head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) char
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    return head tail
}
{ print octs2chars($0) }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
backslash \ is escaped as \134
single quote ' and double quote "
linefeed `
` and carriage return `
%s &
etc...
```

If you don't have GNU awk then write a small function to convert octal to decimal, e.g. `oct2dec()` below, and then call that instead of `strtonum()`:

```
$ cat tst2.awk
function oct2dec(oct,   dec) {
    dec =  substr(oct,1,1) * 8 * 8
    dec += substr(oct,2,1) * 8
    dec += substr(oct,3,1)
    return dec
}

function octs2chars(str,        head,tail,oct,dec,char) {
    head = ""
    tail = str
    while ( match(tail,/\\[0-7]{3}/) ) {
        oct  = substr(tail,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
        dec  = oct2dec(oct)        # replaced "strtonum(0 oct)"
        char = sprintf("%c", dec)
        head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) char
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    return head tail
}
{ print octs2chars($0) }
```

```
$ awk -f tst2.awk file
backslash \ is escaped as \134
single quote ' and double quote "
linefeed `
` and carriage return `
%s &
etc...
```

The above assumes that, [as discussed in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73628868/decoding-octal-escape-sequences-in-input-with-awk?noredirect=1#comment130038302_73628868), the only backslashes in the input will be in the context of the start of octal numbers as shown in the provided sample input.

Comment: You're right, the target `awk` isn't GNU, and you posted your POSIX solution while I was debugging mine ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU awk` which supports `strtonum()` function, would you
please try:

```
awk '{
    while (match($0, /\\[0-7]{1,3}/)) {
        printf("%s", substr($0, 1, RSTART - 1))                      # print the substring before the match
        printf("%c", strtonum("0" substr($0, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH)))  # convert the octal string to character
        $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH)                            # update $0 with remaining substring
    }
    print
}' input_file
```

- It processes the matched substring (octal presentation)
  in the `while` loop one by one.
- `substr($0, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH)` skips the leading backslash.
- `"0"` prepended to `substr` makes an octal string.
- `strtonum()` converts the octal string to the numeric value.
- The final `print` outputs the remaining substring.

Comment: On my system (GNU Awk 4.1.4) it prints `"backslash "\\"134"` *before* the pipeline to `xargs` and the final result looks as `backslash\ \\134`.

Comment: Sorry It's my fault; my attempt didn't work because you already `printf` parts of `$0` before calling `print`

Comment: @tshiono : i think `match($0, /\\[0-7]{1,3}/)` would be more apt, since `\42` is as equally valid as `\042` in terms of expression a single byte of the double-quotation mark `(")`

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*I got my own POSIX `awk` solution, so I post it here for reference.*</sub>

The main idea is to build a hash that translates an octal escape sequence to its corresponding character. You can then use it while splitting the line during the search for escape sequences:

```bash
LANG=C awk '
    BEGIN {
        for ( i = 1; i <= 255; i++ )
            tr[ sprintf("\\%03o",i) ] = sprintf("%c",i)
    }
    {
        remainder = $0
        while ( match(remainder, /\\[0-7]{3}/) ) {
            printf("%s%s", \
                   substr(remainder, 1, RSTART-1), \
                   tr[ substr(remainder, RSTART, RLENGTH) ] \
            )
            remainder = substr(remainder, RSTART + RLENGTH)
        }
        print remainder
    }
' input.txt
```

```
backslash `\`
single quote `'` and double quote `"`
linefeed `
` and carriage return `
%s &
etc...
```

Comment: Nice idea pre-populating the mapping array.

Comment: @Fravadona : why limit to `ASCII` range ? this can't decode any multi-byte `UTF-8`. another tip - for `\060` to `\067`, just trim out `\06` part and leave last digit

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto The characters in the question is a subset of ASCII (`0x01-0x1F 0x22 0x5C 0x7F`), so the ASCII range is enough; but you're right, it doesn't hurt to go up to `0xFF`

Comment: @Fravadona : so that's my challenge for u - how to extend ur same octal concept to every byte in `gawk` without invocating byte mode, setting `LC_ALL or LANG to C / POSIX / anything-ASCII`, command line variable assignment, triggering and/or artificially suppressing any warning messages, or using `getline`.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto I don't understand, what would be the input and the expected output?

Comment: @Fravadona : : it's a generic question - but i'l just directly tell u the answer - see my post below. With this framework, I could even octal-encode binary files like `.mp3` and have `gawk unicode-mode` decode out the exact original input song, but for the `x80-xFF` bytes, one can only use `gsub( )` to replace, since any calls to `match( )`, `length( )`, or `substr( )` would very likely trigger warning/error messages.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto The octal escape sequence for `U+01B6` would be `\306\266`, not `\666`

Comment: @Fravadona : yes that's correct, but it's not a bi-directional mapping : `printf '\u01B6'` gives u `\306\266`, but  `printf '\666'` gives u just `\266`. Run `gawk -e 'BEGIN { print sprintf("%c",strtonum("0666")), "\666" }'` if u don't believe me

Comment: @Fravadona : `gawk -nbe 'BEGIN { print _=(_+=(_^=_<_)+_)^(_+_)+_*(_+_)-_^(__=++_), _=+((_<_)_), _%=__^__, sprintf("\\%03o",_) }' 
666 438 182 \266` — `gawk` sees an integer of `666`, but when interpreted as octal, its decimal value becomes `438`, `mod %` it by `4^4. or 256`, and the result is `\266` - but u only apply that modulo when the octal is preceded by backslash - standalone octal values don't need any modulo

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE :: about `gawk`'s `strtonum()` in unicode mode :

```
echo '\666' | 

  LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8' gawk -e '

  $++NF = "<( "(sprintf("%c", strtonum((_=_<_) substr($++_, ++_))))" )>"'

0000000         909522524       539507744       690009798            2622
           \   6   6   6       <   (       ƶ  **       )   >  \n        
          134 066 066 066 040 074 050 040 306 266 040 051 076 012        
           \   6   6   6  sp   <   (  sp   ?   ?  sp   )   >  nl        
           92  54  54  54  32  60  40  32 198 182  32  41  62  10        
           5c  36  36  36  20  3c  28  20  c6  b6  20  29  3e  0a        

0000016
```

By default, `gawk` in unicode mode would decode out a multi-byte character instead of byte `\266 | 0xB6`. If you wanna ensure consistency of always decoding out a single-byte out, even in `gawk` unicode mode, this should do the trick :

```
echo '\666' | 

     LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8' gawk -e '$++NF = sprintf("<( %c )>",

                 strtonum((_=_<_) substr($++_, ++_)) + _*++_^_++*_^++_)'

0000000         909522524       539507744      1042882742              10
           \   6   6   6       <   (     266       )   >  \n            
          134 066 066 066 040 074 050 040 266 040 051 076 012            
           \   6   6   6  sp   <   (  sp   ?  sp   )   >  nl            
           92  54  54  54  32  60  40  32 182  32  41  62  10            
           5c  36  36  36  20  3c  28  20  b6  20  29  3e  0a            

0000015
```

***long story short*** : add `4^5 * 54` to output of `strtonum()`, which happens to be `0xD800`, the starting point of `UTF-16 surrogates`

=================== =================== ===================

one quick note about `@Gene`'s proposed `perl`-based solution :

```
echo 'abc \555 456' | perl -p -e 's/\\([0-7]{3})/chr(oct($1))/ge'

Wide character in print at -e line 1, <> line 1.
abc ŭ 456
```

octal codes wrap around, meaning `\4xx = \0xx ; \6xx = \2xx` etc :

```
printf '\n %s\n' $'\555'

 m
```

so `perl` is incorrectly decoding these as multi-byte characters, when in fact `\555`, as confirmed by `printf`, is merely lowercase `"m" (0x6D)`

ps : my `perl` is version `5.34`

Comment: Nice remark, but I would say that `0555` is equal to `0x16D`, so I'm not sure that stripping it to `0x6D` like printf is the right thing to do. perl translates it to `U+016D`

Comment: @Fravadona : ah ha there's the difference : if it's purely `0555`, then yes you're correct, but since the question pertains specifically to `\nnn` notation, which is an octal format that's only used to describe individual bytes IIRC, then `printf` is correct not `perl` - i tested it on `gnu-printf`, `bsd-printf`, plus the `zsh` built-in one, plus every single `awk` variant i have, and all gave me the lowercase `m` - so you're welcomed to submit bug-reports for all of them.

Comment: They're not buggy, their `printf` is POSIX compliant: `"\ddd", where ddd is a one, two, or three-digit octal number, shall be written as a byte with the numeric value specified by the octal number.`

Comment: @Fravadona : exactly …. `"written as ` ***`a byte"`***, so why are you arguing multi-byte output is correct ?

Comment: I don't think gawk (5.1.1) parses octal strings correctly. For example: `"\4777"` becomes `3F 37` in hex. One might expect `27 37 37` instead. It is clear that `477` is bigger than `377` or `0xFF`, so it should only parse `\47`. Futhermore `"\256"` should become `C2 AE` for UTF-8 locale and `AE` if `--characters-as-bytes` is supplied.

Comment: @Darkman : i'm not on the dev teams of any of the software mentioned above, so my opinion means absolutely nothing - youre most welcomed to file a bug report with the `gnu-gawk` team instead to address your findings =)

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto It is not that simple. What about the hex strings e.g. `"\x00-\xFF"`. It will be complicated for the regexp `/[\x00-\xFF]/` or `"[\\x00-\\xFF]"` especially if want to use a variable for the regexp. By converting them to UTF- 8 by default, will make it the regex harder/simpler (to you) but one thing for sure will break old codes.

Comment: @Darkman : why are you trying to convince me ? I have no control over the `gawk` source code, and I don't sit on `POSIX` committees. Even if I were to fully concur with your perspective, nothing changes till you raise your concerns with the right folks. As for how to deal with `UTF-8`, i'll show you an example of my own (still buggy) codes how i translate those hex and octals for japanese: `function isJapanese(_) { return (_~/\343(\201|\202|\203|\200(\205|\222|\244|\251|\261|\262|\263|\264|\265|\266)|\207(\260|\261|\262|\263|\264|\265|\266|\267|\270|\271|\272|\273|\274|\275|\276|\277))/) }`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto It is called discussions. That is the reason this comment section is for. I by no mean to convince anybody whatsoever.

Comment: @Darkman : what about those hex strings ?  that's why in other langs, such as `perl` (IIRC), they use `\x{F8FF}` for `UTF-8` code point of `U+ F8FF`, while `\xB9` etc has always been used to describe a single byte -  e.g. `\xF8FF` describes a single byte `0xF8`, then `ASCII` letters `F`, twice - a 3 byte sequence. hex doesn't have the wrap-around issue that octals encounter (not really an `"issue"` per se more nuances to be mindful of. i'm no big fan of `gawk`, to be honest, but I do believe `gawk 5.1.1` doesn't have any issues decoding the hex and octals, in code and in data.

Answer (score 0):

this separate post is made specifically to showcase how to extend the octal lookup reference tables in `gawk` `unicode`-mode to ***`all 256 bytes`*** without external dependencies or warning messages:

- `ASCII` bytes reside in table `o2bL`
- 8-bit bytes reside in table `o2bH`

.

```
   # gawk profile, created Fri Sep 16 09:53:26 2022

   'BEGIN {
 1      makeOctalRefTables(PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc" \
                                            (ORS = ""))
128     for (_ in o2bL) {
128        print o2bL[_]
        }
128     for (_ in o2bH) {
128        print o2bH[_]
        }
   }

   function makeOctalRefTables(_,__,___,____)
   {
 1    _=__=___=____=""
      for (_ in o2bL) {
         break
      }
 1    if (!(_ in o2bL)) {

 1        ____=_+=((_+=_^=_<_)-+-++_)^_--

128        do { o2bL[sprintf("\\%o",_)] = \
                     sprintf("""%c",_)

           } while (_--)

 1         o2bL["\\" ((_+=(_+=_^=_<_)+_)*_--+_+_)] = "\\&"

 1         ___=--_*_^_--*--_*++_^_*(_^=++_)^(! —_)

128        do { o2bH[sprintf("\\%o", +_)] = \
                     sprintf("%c",___+_)

           } while (____<--_)
       }
 1     return length(o2bL) ":" length(o2bH)
   }'
```

|

```
\0 \1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7 \10\11    \12 
\13 
    \14 
\16 \17 
\20 \21 \22 \23 \24 \25 \26 \27 \30 \31 \32 \33 34 \35 \36 \37 
\40  \41 !\42 "\43 #\44 $\45 %\47 '\50 (\51 )\52 *\53 +\54 ,\55 -\56 .\57 /
\60 0\61 1\62 2\63 3\64 4\65 5\66 6\67 7\70 8\71 9\72 :\73 ;\74 <\75 =\76 >\77 ?
\100 @\101 A\102 B\103 C\104 D\105 E\106 F\107 G\110 H\111 I\112 J\113 K\114 L\115 M\116 N\117 O
\120 P\121 Q\122 R\123 S\124 T\125 U\126 V\127 W\130 X\131 Y\132 Z\133 [\134 \\46 \&\135 ]\136 ^\137 _
\140 `\141 a\142 b\143 c\144 d\145 e\146 f\147 g\150 h\151 i\152 j\153 k\154 l\155 m\156 n\157 o
\160 p\161 q\162 r\163 s\164 t\165 u\166 v\167 w\170 x\171 y\172 z\173 {\174 |\175 }\176 ~\177 
\200 ?\201 ?\202 ?\203 ?\204 ?\205 ?\206 ?\207 ?\210 ?\211 ?\212 ?\213 ?\214 ?\215 ?\216 ?\217 ?
\220 ?\221 ?\222 ?\223 ?\224 ?\225 ?\226 ?\227 ?\230 ?\231 ?\232 ?\233 ?\234 ?\235 ?\236 ?\237 ?
\240 ?\241 ?\242 ?\243 ?\244 ?\245 ?\246 ?\247 ?\250 ?\251 ?\252 ?\253 ?\254 ?\255 ?\256 ?\257 ?
\260 ?\261 ?\262 ?\263 ?\264 ?\265 ?\266 ?\267 ?\270 ?\271 ?\272 ?\273 ?\274 ?\275 ?\276 ?\277 ?
\300 ?\301 ?\302 ?\303 ?\304 ?\305 ?\306 ?\307 ?\310 ?\311 ?\312 ?\313 ?\314 ?\315 ?\316 ?\317 ?
\320 ?\321 ?\322 ?\323 ?\324 ?\325 ?\326 ?\327 ?\330 ?\331 ?\332 ?\333 ?\334 ?\335 ?\336 ?\337 ?
\340 ?\341 ?\342 ?\343 ?\344 ?\345 ?\346 ?\347 ?\350 ?\351 ?\352 ?\353 ?\354 ?\355 ?\356 ?\357 ?
\360 ?\361 ?\362 ?\363 ?\364 ?\365 ?\366 ?\367 ?\370 ?\371 ?\372 ?\373 ?\374 ?\375 ?\376 ?\377 ?
```